# How would you inject HTML tags into a string, given the start and end index of the injections?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Given a string and a style array render HTML pretty much like a rich text editor.

For example: 'Hello, world', [[0, 2, 'i'], [4, 9, 'b'], [7, 10, 'u']]
Output: `<i>Hel</i>l<b>o, w<u>orl</u></b><u>d</u>`

Keep in mind that  tag gets placed before the  tag and after it as the insertion index overlaps it.

So far this is my answer:

```
function render(str, styles) {
  let res = ""
  let lastIndex = 0
  styles.forEach(([start, end, tag], index) => {
    if(lastIndex > start) {
      res  = res.substring(0,start) +  `<${tag}>` + res.substring(start,lastIndex) + `</${tag}>` + res.substring(lastIndex) 
      start = lastIndex + 1
    }
    let newTaggedString = str.substring(lastIndex,start)  + `<${tag}>` + str.substring(start,end) + `</${tag}>` 
    res+=newTaggedString
    lastIndex = end
  })
  
  if(lastIndex < str.length) {
      res += str.substring(lastIndex) 
  }

  return res
}
```

and it outputs

`"<i>He</<u>i></u>ll<b>o, wo</b>r<u></u>ld"`

Comment: java != javascript != python. so remove unrelated language tags

Comment: The output you specify is not valid HTML

Comment: maybe you should increment an offset variable every time you add an opening or closing tag? and that offset always add to the start and end positions from your tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a stack to keep track of the tags that were previously opened and not closed. And on each letter, check whether a tag needs to be closed *(popped off the stack)*, or a new one opened *(pushed to the stack)*:

```js
function render(str, styles) {
  return str.split('').reduce((res, letter, i, arr) => {
    const tags = styles.reduce((acc, [start, end, tag]) => // Current letter tags
      i >= start && i <= end ? acc.concat(tag) : acc
    , []);
    
    while (res.stack.some(tag => !tags.includes(tag))) {
      res.str += `</${res.stack.pop()}>`; // Pop unwanted tags off the stack
    }
    
    tags.forEach(tag => {
        if (!res.stack.includes(tag)) { // Push wanted tags to the stack
          res.stack.push(tag);
          res.str += `<${tag}>`;
        }
    });

    res.str += letter;

    // If there are tags to close at the end of the string
    if (i === arr.length - 1)
      while (res.stack.length)
        res.str += `</${res.stack.pop()}>`;

    return res;
  }, { stack: [], str: '' }).str;
}

const res = render('Hello, world', [[0, 2, 'i'], [4, 9, 'b'], [7, 10, 'u']]);

document.body.innerHTML = res;
console.log(res);
```

In case you didn't know about [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), here are some docs